# Price Calculations (Based on user input amount levels)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am basing this code off of this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vxupE/

I would love to implement these price levels into my code so that when a person puts in $501 they are charged 20% but if they put in $500 they are charged 25%

```
if $price =< 101 then *.30
if $price > 100 and < 501 then *.25
if $price > 500 and < 1501 then *.20
if $price > 1500 then *.15
```

I'm at a loss when is comes to javascript. I think this could help others though. Would definitely help me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#sub_tot').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var charge = 0;
    if ( value >= 501 ) {
     charge = .25;   
    }
    else if ( value >= 100 ) {
     charge = .20;  
    }
    $('#tax').val( (value * charge).toFixed(2) );
}).change()
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Here is my final code:

`$('#sub_tot').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var charge = 0;
    if ( value < 100 ) {
     charge = .30;   
    }
    else if ( value >= 100 && value < 500 ) {
     charge = .25;  
    }
    else if ( value >= 500 && value < 1500 ) {
     charge = .20;  
    }
    else if ( value >= 1500 ) {
     charge = .15;  
    }
    $('#tax').val( (value * charge).toFixed(2) );
}).change()
`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I would consider.

switch statements, there are plenty of tutorials on line to look through. The other option is is using if and else if To find the correct additional charge.

```
if($price =< 101){
   charge=0.3;
}else if($price>=100){
   charge=0.25;
}else if($price>=500){
   charge=0.2;
}else if($price>=1500){
   charge=0.15;
```

where charge can then be used to calculate the final cost.

UPDATE

your code is checking if your sub total value is equal to your zip code. change

`$('#sub_tot').change(function(){` to `$('#zip').change(function(){ to`

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. :/
`$('#sub_tot').change(function(){
    if('#sub_tot' =< 101){
      x=0.3
}else if('#sub_tot'>=100){
      x=0.25
}else if('#sub_tot'>=500{
     x=0.2
}
    $('#tax').val( ($(this).val()*x ).toFixed(2) );
}).change()`

Comment: try breaking it down there is quite a bit going on here. Rather than do it for you first try on if statement and console log the x value. Add the else if and do the same. There are a couple of basic errors you have made with your selectors.

Comment: `$('#sub_tot').change(function(){
    if('#sub_tot' =< 101){
      $('#tax').val( ($(this).val()*.30 ).toFixed(2) );
}

}).change()`

Breaking it down to just one request, using and numeric multiplier. Doesn't load for me.

Comment: in the if statement '#sub_tot' should be $('#sub_tot')

Comment: `$('#sub_tot').change(function(){
    if $('#sub_tot' =< 101){
      $('#tax').val( ($(this).val()*.30 ).toFixed(2) );
}

}).change()` No good unfortunately.

Comment: see answer by WannaCSharp

Comment: I would like to add another cost based on zip code. Would you be able to check my code out at:

http://jsfiddle.net/vxupE/62/

and tell me what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to use the same principles. It may have something to do with my variables.